# Eclipse: Pydev keeps on changing my settings

Tags: pydev

1. I am trying to turn `autopep8` off in Window->Preferences->PyDev->Editor->Code Style->Code Formatter. But on  the next Eclipse restart the tickbox is set again. I tried adding `FORMAT_WITH_AUTOPEP8=false` in the .prefs file, but that gets overwritten.
2. I want to remove/add interpreters in Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreters. But on the next Eclipse restart the removed ones are back and the newly set ones are not there.

Answer (score 0):

Humm... usually those preferences are written under the workspace you selected, so, my guess is that your user probably doesn't have the needed rights to write to that folder (i.e.: check the attributes for the folders beneath the '.metadata' of your selected workspace).

You can try to point to a new workspace in a new folder in your home to see if it's persisted there.

If that's not the case, please report on whether you have something in your error log and what OS are you on (see http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F for details on getting the error log).

Comment: Excuse me for forgetting:
Running Win10-64 bit: the workspaces are in c:Users/Josy/ and thus *writable*.
I once painstakingly searched all files and removed all occurrences for the removed Python Interpreters, but to no avail. On the next Eclipse restart ... yes, they were back.

Comment: Humm... can you try specifying a different workspace to see if it works? Also, is c:Users/Josy/` the actual path to the workspace specified? If that's the case, make sure you write it as `c:\Users\Josy\my_workspace` (i.e.: with windows slashes and with a slash after the colon). If that doesn't fix it, pleas. check the info on the error log.

Comment: I'm going to split this thread into two: one for the autopep8 function and one for the interpreter functionality. It may be the same bug/issue, but let;s find out one at a time. So I will close this tread.